# Wicket turns form into a div and panel into a form

Tags: java, wicket

I currently have a tabbed panel inside a model window in which I want a form to exists.

Everything is working properly, BUT the form declared in my markup is turned into a DIV and the panel into a form.

Below you can see my 
1. markup for the modal window, 
2. the code of the button which created the component within a page
3. the markup of my form being added to the SubmitToRegistrarPanel
4. The resulting html ...

This prohibits me from controlling action, onSubmit etc... ultimately, I want to set the original action of the form, when the panel is being created in such a way it will first post to an external CAS, then come back as a service to the handler (back to wicket)so I can get a service ticket.

Please help, thanks.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you put the ModalWindow inside a form?

https://ci.apache.org/projects/wicket/apidocs/6.x/org/apache/wicket/extensions/ajax/markup/html/modal/ModalWindow.html

"If you want to use form in modal window component make sure that you put the modal window itself in another form (nesting forms is legal in Wicket) and that the form on modal window is submitted before the window get closed."

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The form within the ModalWindow IS working ok. The problem is that the markup is changed! the ModalWindow itself is a Panel, which contains a form insider. I would like the markup i created for the <form> not to be converted into a div.

Comment: Don't fight your tools - this is how ModalWindow is working right now. You can easily roll your own modal dialogs with some custom JavaScript.

Comment: Actually, funny enough, the opposite worked for me. I removed the form from WITHIN the original parent one (page, which then opens a panel with the form inside), and now the form is not getting replaced by divs - this is the HTML specification btw, so I wasn't surprised by it. Anyhow, thank you for brainstorming, i will mark it as correct since it pointed me towards the right mindset